# Creating and loading multiple iframes dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to add few ifamres to a page based on the search result from the database.
Also I am planing to put those I frames inside a Jquery-UI accordion menu. What is the best way of doing this. I have used PHP for creating the ifamres dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchResult(url){
    $("<iframe>").attr("src", url).appendTo("div#result");
}

searchResult("//www.example.com");
```